# Is there a way bring down the iron bars behind Clavicus Vile in Haemar's Shrine?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

There seems to be a [metal bars-esque barrier](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x56bu.jpg) in the passage behind Clavicus Vile in Haemar's Shame/Haemar's Shrine. Is there a way to open it?

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Go up to the door, directly to the right of the door is a chain on the wall. If you can't find it I'll post a SS when I get home.

Edit:
If you zoom in on your SS you can see it, snip here.
[image]

Took me a while to find it as well, and I did look for it, I didn't find it till I came back the second time.